# Why is the Universe anisotropic to a non-comoving observer?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, universe, space-expansion, observable-universe

Our cosmology course instructor said that

> At a given cosmic time $t=\tau$, the comoving observers define a **spacelike** hypersurface $\Sigma$ in which the universe looks homogenous and isotropic. Another observer, who is moving with a uniform velocity w.r.t the class of comoving observers will find the universe to be anisotropic. An intergalactic spaceship moving at a high speed would see the galactic distribution quite differently.

I have several questions based on his statement.

1. What does he mean by "the comoving observers define a **spacelike** hypersurface $\Sigma$."?
2. Is it that the homogeneity and isotropy of the Universe true only for the comoving observers? If yes, why?

Comment: re 1, tangent vectors to $\Sigma$ have space-like norm (ie positive or negative depending on sign convention of the metric tensor), re 2, length contraction will distort the matter distribution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bit about the spacelike hypersurface is simply a complex way of saying those observers can define their own notion of simultaneity. They pick a slice of space and say "the time value is the same everywhere here. I HAVE SPOKEN!". Of course, they have to define it in a way that preserves homogeneity and isotropy, but they can always do this if they are truly comoving.

When he says the non-comoving observers will see the universe as anisotropic, this is because of special relativity. Any peculiar velocity blue-shifts the CMB in front of you and red-shifts it behind you. Furthermore, the distribution of structures in the universe changes when you have a peculiar velocity because of how length contraction alters how you perceive relative densities at various angle from your direction of motion. We can see these effects from Earth. Both the [WMAP](https://map.gsfc.nasa.gov/) and [Planck](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Science/Planck) data sets had to have the dipole anisotropy removed from the [CMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background) data because of our roughly $360\,{\rm km}\,{\rm s}^{-1}$ peculiar velocity.